# How can I whitelist any IP address using a AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a basic S3 Bucket and am trying to whitelist IP addresses that can access it.
I tried using the following standard bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::polynians/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "142.250.200.14"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I run `curl -H "Origin: 142.250.200.14" -v https:...` I receive a 403 forbidden response.

When I remove the condition - ie allowing every IP address to access my bucket - it works as intended, ie I get 200 OK responses from any origin.

Is there something wrong with my condition?

Comment: You can't fool it with the Origin header, your IP actually has to be the IP you specified.

Comment: I removed the Origin header from the command line `curl -H "142.250.200.14" -v https:..`, but still get a 403 error. Still works for all IPs when I remove the condition from the bucket policy.

Comment: Is your public IP actually the IP you specified?

Comment: No, that was another website. I tried with my public IP address and it worked. But then why does the condition not work with other IP addresses? How can I grant access to my bucket to a website so that it can fetch data from my bucket?

Comment: It does work for other IP addresses. What do you mean by "grant access to a website"?

Comment: You can't spoof ip address with header. You must actually have such ip address.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the issues is that the host that performs the API call actually has to have its public IP match the resource policy. You cannot use the `Origin` header for this.

To test this, make sure the machine that you're using to make the call has this IP. To find out your public IP, use a service like https://ifconfig.me.